# How to get variable from $.getScript in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions `country` and `location`. When the page loads these two functions will run.

I need to get the `result` value from `$.getScript` and use it in the function `location()`.

Currently, I am getting `undefined`. Please check my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var result;

        function country() {
            $.getScript("ajax/country.js", function () {
                result = 'data one'; // I need to get this result in location().
            });
        }

        function location() {
            console.log(result); // This result should be 'data one'. Currently, I am getting undefined.
        }

        country();

        location();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: `result = 'data one'; location();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.getScript()` works asynchronous. Call `location` in the `getScript` function.

```
$(function () {
    function country() {
        $.getScript("ajax/country.js", function () {
            let result = 'data one'; // I need to get this result in location().
            location(result);
        });
    }

    function location(result) {
        console.log(result); // This result should be 'data one'. Currently, I am getting undefined.
    }

    country();
});
```